# Flow Builder - Won't Retrieve Records

Tags: visual-workflow

Everybody,
Long time reader, first time poster...
Building my first Flow, and striking out already.
Scenario:
Loan custom object
Related list custom object called Related Entities, with a Lookup field back to Loan
From Loan, click custom button "Request Documents", which uses GetRecords element to query Related Entities where Loan__c = {!$Flow.CurrentRecord}

I've tried retrieving all data, and "Choose fields and assign variables", but neither way returns any data.
When I remove the Conditions of the query, the query does find Related Entities.
[image: GetRecords query]

After I find the records, I want to display them in a list of checkboxes, but I can't even get the records I want yet. (Yes, I'd love some help with that, but I guess that's a second question)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much! I promise I'll get pretty self sufficient with these after a bit, but would love some help getting over initial hurdles.

[image: GetRecords query]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the value to the {!$Flow.CurrentRecord} variable first to avoid passing null values.Please check the [article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_pause_recordassoc.htm&type=5) on how to set the value and try again.

Comment: Super helpful. Thanks so much, Shirisha!

Comment: Can you please mark it as best answer so that this post can be closed.